# In Rails what is next step after creating a controller to get data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails application I have created a controller to get data from database which also includes params in model as follows.

The problem is that there are no html pages in views folder.. Do I need to run the controller??? I want the output i json format.. How are the html pages  created and where  can i see my json format of data...

```
# shoppingDemo.rb (controller)
class ShoppingDemo < ApplicationController
  def index
    @lists=products.all;
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @lists}
    end
  end

  def show
    @products = products.find(params[:prod_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end
end

# products(model)
class products < Activerecord::Base
  attr_accessible :model_name, :brand_name, :price, :discount, :qty_available
end
```

What is the next step to create html pages or to see my data from database in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix some issues:

1) in Model

`class Product`

2) in Controller

`@lists = Product.all`

`@products = Product.find(params[:id])`

3) You should create routes in `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :products
```

It will create routes for index, show, new, create, update, destroy actions. Read more [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

After that you can access your products list through http request on `http://localhost:3000/products` and show your product with id=1 on `http://localhost:3000/products/1`

Comment: Thank U for giving me the support.. I have a doubt.. in my database the table name is 'products'.. then wehre i ave to declare that one??? i want to get hte answer for the query 'select * from products'.. how to write this in query in rails??

Comment: table `products` relates to `Product` model.
query `select * from products` is `Product.all`
Read this tutorial - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: In my routes.rb everyline is commented.. and i made 'resources : products' ... Do i need to uncomment all the lines or the single line???

Comment: if you need to operate only with products, then one line will be enough. and of course the first and last lines should be presented: `YourApp::Application.routes.draw do` and `end`

Comment: but still i am having the error as 'uninitialized constant ShoppingDemosController' when i run it

Comment: The best choice is to read the link I've gave you above. The more detailed manual you can find here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: The reason you are getting 'uninitialized constant ShoppingDemosController' is because your route is pointing to the wrong controller.  Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it manually.  To do that just create the `shopping_demo` folder in the views directory .  Then in `shopping_demo` directory create the **index.html.erb** and **show.html.erb** files.

Now if you want to access the json data just append .json format specifier like so `http://localhost:3000/path_to_resource/1.json`.  Make sure to replace path_to_resource with the name of resource you are trying to access.

First rename your **shoppingDemo.rb** file to **shopping_demo_controller.rb**.  Then in the **shopping_demo_controller.rb** file change the class name to **ShoppingDemoController**.  And lastly place this `resources :shopping_demo` just below `ShoppingDemo::Application.routes.draw do` in your routes.rb file.

Comment: I'm not too sure, I don't use the Aptana IDE.  You will be able to see the json output in your browser though.  Just make sure you start your rails server and then point your browser to the address of your resource.

Comment: Thank u ... its working. I got the output in json format what i required, but it shows when i simply declare localhost:3000/products it shows template missing. if i give localhost:3000/products.json then it shows my data.. what may be the error??

Comment: Make sure you have the `index.html.erb` view file in the `app/views/products` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is an MVC framework. MVC stands for Model View Controller.

The html you say exists in the Views.

For index action of ShoppingDemo controller create this file

```
app/views/shoppingdemo/index.html.erb
```

and write the appropriate code inside.
eg

```
<% @lists.each do |list| %>
  <%= list %>
<% end %>
```

Also you have a typo. When you call a  Model you should do it with the first letter capital.

eg
Instead of

```
@lists = products.all #WRONG
```

do

```
@lists = Product.all #Plural the first letter and singular for the model.
```